# Non-root extension fields in docker compose 3.7

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

The [docs for 3.7](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) say that:

> Starting with the 3.7 format (for the 3.x series) and 2.4 format (for the 2.x series), extension fields are also allowed at the root of service, volume, network, config and secret definitions.

So I thought I could do this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  x-logging: &default-logging    # within services, rather than document root
    driver: json-file
  web:
    image: myapp/web:latest
    logging: *default-logging
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    logging: *default-logging
```

But when I try something like this, I get the error:

> Top-level object must be a mapping